# Crash when erasing element from unordered_set in loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, unordered-set

I have some code that tries to erase certain elements from an unordered_set. It is done in a loop. The crash happens after it removes the first element found. I currently don't have any other setup except an M1 Mac. The crash happens there but doesn't on online sites (such as Coliru). I am wondering if my code has any undefined behavior. Comments are welcome. Thanks a lot!

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

bool operator==(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
{
    return p1.x == p2.x && p1.y == p2.y;
}

struct PointHash
{
    std::size_t operator() (const Point& p) const {
        return std::hash<int>()(p.x) ^ std::hash<int>()(p.y);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<Point, PointHash> S{Point{0,1}, Point{1,1}, Point{1,0}, Point{2,0}};
    for (auto it = S.begin(); it != S.end(); ++it) {
        if (it->x == 0)
            it = S.erase(it);
    }

    for (auto&& p: S)
        std::cout << p.x << ',' << p.y << std::endl;
}
```

Please not that I also tried for-range on the erase loop but got the same crash.

Comment: Use the [Erase Remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) to remove elements from standard containers.

Comment: You're double-advancing the iterator on delete (once in the erase result, another in the incr-step of the for loop). Take out the for loop incr-step and move it to an `else` condition post-if within the loop.

Comment: Thank you @WhozCraig!  I got your point.  How about using for-range?  Does it have the same problem?

Comment: @HongzhengWang Worse. Don't even bother trying ranged-for on a container with inner-loop element presence volatility. What you had was almost right. Just move the increment as an alternate to erasure within the loop. Or, if the algorithms work for you things like erase/remove mechanics would be even more preferable.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you. I agree.  using erase remove idiom will not have the problem in the first place. The reason I chose loop is because my original code updated instead of deleting. Later I added more logic in the loop to delete certain nodes and caused the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the for loop like

```
for (auto it = S.begin(); it != S.end(); ) {
    if (it->x == 0)
        it = S.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

If the compiler supports C++ 20 then you can just write

```
std::erase_if( S, []( const auto &p ) { return p.x == 0; } );
```

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

bool operator==(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
{
    return p1.x == p2.x && p1.y == p2.y;
}

struct PointHash
{
    std::size_t operator() (const Point& p) const {
        return std::hash<int>()(p.x) ^ std::hash<int>()(p.y);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<Point, PointHash> S{Point{0,1}, Point{1,1}, Point{1,0}, Point{2,0}};

    for ( const auto &p : S )
        std::cout << p.x << ',' << p.y << std::endl;

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::erase_if( S, []( const auto &p ) { return p.x == 0; } );

    for ( const auto &p : S)
        std::cout << p.x << ',' << p.y << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
2,0
1,1
1,0
0,1

2,0
1,1
1,0
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  My account cannot vote up yet.  But my feedback has been recorded.

Comment: @HongzhengWang Just mark the answer as the best answer and your reputation will be increased.